# Condition is always true when reached?

Tags: kotlin

Assume moves on a map which is 41 wide by 19 high. Note that the coordinates (X and Y) start at the top left!

This means the most top left cell has the coordinates "X=0,Y=0" and the most bottom right one has the coordinates "X=40,Y=18".

I am confused what am I doing wrong hear, is the directions is also displayed wrong?

This code is running for ever until energy drained!

```
import kotlin.random.Random

fun main() {
    var energy = 100
    val lightX = Random.nextInt(0, 40)
    val lightY = Random.nextInt(0, 18)
    val initialTx = Random.nextInt(0, 40)
    val initialTy = Random.nextInt(0, 18)

    var moveX = initialTx
    var moveY = initialTy

    println("Start: ($initialTx, $initialTy)")
    println("End: ($lightX, $lightY)")

    while (energy > 0) { // Condition always true
        when {
            lightX > initialTx && lightY == initialTy -> {
                println("E")
                moveX++
                println("Continue: ($moveX, $moveY)")
            }
            lightX < initialTx && lightY == initialTy -> {
                println("W")
                moveX--
                println("Continue: ($moveX, $moveY)")
            }
            lightX == initialTx && lightY > initialTy -> {
                println("S")
                moveX++
                println("Continue: ($moveX, $moveY)")
            }
            lightX == initialTx && lightY < initialTy -> {
                println("N")
                moveY--
                println("Continue: ($moveX, $moveY)")
            }
            lightX > initialTx && lightY > initialTy -> {
                println("SE")
                moveX++
                moveY++
                println("Continue: ($moveX, $moveY)")
            }
            lightX < initialTx && lightY > initialTy -> {
                println("SW")
                moveX--
                moveY++
                println("Continue: ($moveX, $moveY)")
            }
            lightX > initialTx && lightY < initialTy -> { // Condition always true when reached
                println("NE")
                moveX++
                moveY--
                println("Continue: ($moveX, $moveY)")
            }
            lightX < initialTx && lightY < initialTy -> { // Condition always true when reached
                println("NW")
                moveX--
                moveY--
                println("Continue: ($moveX, $moveY)")
            }
        }
        energy--
    }
}
```

WebSite: [Codingame thor game](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/power-of-thor-episode-1)

Image: [image: Console and code]

Comment: But what is the problem?

Comment: @broot this code is not working for this solution "https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/power-of-thor-episode-1"

Comment: @Deadlooks Please be more specific than just '... is not working'. What exactly is not working? For example: With which input values do you not get the 'light' coordinates?

Comment: For N and S directions you have your Y conditions wrong - they are swapped. But I'm still not sure what exactly is the problem you observe.

Comment: Well, more precise would be to say you have your printlns swapped for N and S, because changes to Y are according to conditions.

Comment: The code in the printscreen is different than you provided above. You modify `move*` variables, but you compare `initial*` vars.

Comment: @broot thanks man i will debug the code now as you said i was mistaking by comparing the `initial*` instead of `move*` and updated post 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253174/discussion-between-deadlooks-and-broot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare against the wrong variables:

```
while (energy > 0) { // Condition always true
  when {
    lightX > initialTx && lightY == initialTy -> {
      ...
```

... should be:

```
while (energy > 0) { // Condition always true
  when {
    lightX > moveX && lightY == moveY -> {
      ...
```

... et cetera for all the other cases. Then the code will run just fine.

A shorter version (and grouped by the x-axis):

```
var energy = 100
val lightX = kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(0, 41)
val lightY = kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(0, 19)
val initialTx = kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(0, 41)
val initialTy = kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(0, 19)

println("Start: ($initialTx, $initialTy)")
println("End: ($lightX, $lightY)")

var moveX = initialTx
var moveY = initialTy

while (0 < energy--) {
  when {
    lightX < moveX  -> {
      moveX--
      when {
        lightY < moveY  -> moveY--.also { println("NW -> ($moveX, $moveY)") }
        lightY == moveY ->                println("W  -> ($moveX, $moveY)")
        lightY > moveY  -> moveY++.also { println("SW -> ($moveX, $moveY)") }
      }
    }
    lightX == moveX -> when {
      lightY < moveY  -> moveY--.also { println("S  -> ($moveX, $moveY)") }
      lightY == moveY -> break          // We arrived
      lightY > moveY  -> moveY++.also { println("N  -> ($moveX, $moveY)") }
    }
    lightX > moveX  -> {
      moveX++
      when {
        lightY < moveY  -> moveY--.also { println("NE -> ($moveX, $moveY)") }
        lightY == moveY ->                println("E  -> ($moveX, $moveY)")
        lightY > moveY  -> moveY++.also { println("SE -> ($moveX, $moveY)") }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the values of `initialTx` and `initialTy` are not being updated, the conditions for the cases "NE" and "NW" are always true. This could lead to an infinite loop.

The conditions for "NE" and "NW" situations can be updated to include a check also for `initialTy > lightY` like following:

```kotlin
lightX > initialTx && lightY < initialTy && initialTy > lightY -> { /* Condition is always true when reached */
//...
            }

lightX < initialTx && lightY < initialTy && initialTy > lightY -> { /* Condition is always true when reached */
//...
            }
```

The condition was always true because `initialTy` is initialized as random which is always less than `lightY` which is also the random digit.

- As a result, an infinite loop will be avoided because the requirements will only be met when initialTy is higher than lightY.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense to me. New conditions you added are exactly the same as existing ones - you only swapped operands. Also, why random is always less than another random?

Comment: Sorry Guys See the updated code!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the conditions for the "NE" and "NW" directions. As you pointed out, these conditions are always true, which causes the loop to keep going forever.

you have to change this lines :

```
lightX > initialTx && lightY < initialTy -> {
    println("NE")
    initialTx++
    initialTy--
    println("Continue: ($initialTx, $initialTy)")
}
lightX < initialTx && lightY < initialTy -> {
    println("NW")
    initialTx--
    initialTy--
    println("Continue: ($initialTx, $initialTy)")
}
```

Comment: Sorry Guys See the updated code!